# CakePHP - Storing foreign keys

Tags: cakephp

I have three models:

1. User
2. Note
3. Comment

A user can have multiples notes (by notes I mean status like Facebook) and a note can have multiple comments.

In the comment table, I want to store user_id and note_id which are actually foreign keys.

Comment controller:

```
public function userscomment()
{
    if (!empty($this->data))
    {
        $commentdata = $this->data;
        $commentdata['Comment']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Comment->save($commentdata);
    }
```

Now as the user id is easily identified, it is stored in the database, but how do I identify that the comment is for this note?

How do I store the id of the note on which the comment is made?

Comment: You would usually have a hidden form input on your page with the note id: `<input type="hidden" name="data[Comment][note_id]" value="4" />`

Comment: Can you please be more clear, i did not get you

Answer (score 0):

In your View, where you have your form for entering a comment, you could specify a form action that sends the note ID to your controller like this:

**app/View/Comments/userscomment.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Comment', array(
    'url' => array('385')  // 385 is the note_id
));
echo $this->Form->textarea('comment');

echo $this->Form->end('Submit Comment');
```

**app/Controller/CustomersController.php**

```
public function userscomment($note_id) {

    if (!empty($this->data)) {

        $commentdata = $this->data;
        $commentdata['Comment']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $commentdata['Comment']['note_id'] = $note_id;
        $this->Comment->save($commentdata);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is what actually the problem it. Here you have manually entered the id but i don`t know how to call the id automatically. Like every note has a unique id so how to call that as we are calling user id by Auth component.

Comment: Okay, well somewhere you must know the note ID in the view, no?  Otherwise how do you display the note or the comments that are already there? Can you post your view HTML so I can have a look?

Comment: Check the view and controller below.

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLER:

public function notesview()
      {

```
 $allnotes = $this->User->Note->find('all', array('order'=>'Note.created DESC'));


    if (!empty($this->params['requested'])) 
      {            
        return $allnotes;        
      } 
  }
```

VIEW:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->css('notes'); 
echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery','jquery.elastic','notes'));
?>
<div class="notescontainer">
<div class="share">Share:</div>
<div class="notes">Notes</div>
<div class="loading"></div>
<div class="img_top"></div>
<div class="text_status">

<?php 
echo $this->form->create('Note', array('action' => 'notes', 'onSubmit' => 'return loadingicon();'));
echo $this->form->input('notes',array('class'=>'notesbar','label'=>'','placeholder'=>'Write down you notes ...' ));
?>
 </div>
<div class="button_outside_border" id="share">
<div class="button_inside_border">

<?php 
echo $this->form->submit('Share',array('class' => 'sharebutton'));
echo $this->form->end();
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<?php 

$allnotes = $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'notesview'));
foreach($allnotes as $viewnotes):
{
    echo "<div class='load_status'>"; 

    echo "<img class='status_img' src="; echo $viewnotes['User']['image']; echo ">"; 

    echo "<div class='status_text'>" ?>

    <a href="users/profileview/<?php echo $viewnotes['User']['id']?>" class='blue'> 
    <?php
    echo $viewnotes['User']['name'];
    echo "</a>";

    echo "<p class='text'>"; 
    echo $viewnotes['Note']['notes']; 
    echo "</p>"; 


    echo " 
    <a href='#' class='light_blue'>Like</a> &middot; 
    <a href='#' class='light_blue'>Comment</a> &middot ";
    echo "<u class='date'>"; echo $viewnotes['Note']['created']; echo"</u>";

    echo $this->element('comments');

    echo "</div>";


    echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
    echo "</div>";


}
endforeach;
 ?>
```